# PostgreSQL comparing daterange and date using less/greater than (< or >) vs strictly left/right of (<< or >>)

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, when querying a daterange field for ranges fully before or after some date, which of the following is the more canonical pattern? Is either more performant?

**1.**
Comparing the date to the upper/lower value of the range and using less than/greater than operators, e.g.:

```
select * from mytable where upper(mydateranges) <= '2000-01-02';
```

**2.**
Or, turning the date into a daterange with an infinite upper/lower bound and using strictly left of/strictly right of operators, e.g.:

```
select * from mytable where mydateranges << '[2000-01-02,]';
```

---

The above examples would be referencing a table created like so:

```
create table mytable (mydateranges daterange);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the first variant because

1. I think that is more readable
2. it can be supported by a B-tree index on `upper(mydateranges)`